# How to show unique constrains error in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Hi I'm very new to `node` and `mongodb`.

How to get the column name which is violating uniqueness rule.I'm getting error message

```
    {
      name: 'MongoError',
      message: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: myCab.users.$phone_1 dup key: { : 9145780834.0 }',
     driver: true,
     code: 11000,
     index: 0,
     errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: myCab.users.$phone_1 dup key: { : 9145780834.0 }',
    getOperation: [Function],
    toJSON: [Function],
    toString: [Function]
  }
```

But I need to customize the error message, so that it can be use directly at front-end because it might be possible that there are two columns which has unique constrints, So for this I need column name

Comment: Isn't it in the error message?

Comment: Why you want to throw error, instead use `count` before saving new data to know if the value already exists.

Comment: as an api I need to send response to front-end that "this bla bla" column is duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the field name by:

```
var fieldName = err.message.substring(err.message.lastIndexOf('index: ') + 7, err.message.lastIndexOf('_1'));
```

You can put it in a function, and call it when the code is `11000` or `11001`. Try this:

```
function getUniqueErrorMessage(err)
{
  var output;
  try
  {
    var fieldName = err.message.substring(err.message.lastIndexOf('index: ') + 7, err.message.lastIndexOf('_1'));
    output = fieldName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + fieldName.slice(1) + ' already exists';

  }
  catch (ex)
  {
    output = 'Unique field already exists';
  }

  return output;
};
```

***Side Note:*** Welcome to mongodb. You can stop calling them columns now :)

Comment: It will work, but if mongo changes its error message it will break

Comment: I faced that issue when I deployed this code on a lower mongo version (2.7). So far, I havent found any other solution. I dont think they go on changing things like these, even they know applications depend on it.
Thats why one needs to maintain dependency for specific versions.